# Regular expression to match lines containing n number of words

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to display the 5 most frequent lines containing only two words 
what i have so far is:

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+' text.txt | sort |uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 5
```

Thank you

The problem is that the first part of the code is returning lines that have more than two words:

Answer (score 4):

You need to anchor your regex, add `^` for the line beginning and `$` for the line end, and add the `\+` quantifier to enable more than one letter in each word:

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z]\+ [a-zA-Z]\+$'
```

Comment: adding ^ worked, but adding the "$" is resulting in no output 

[cmps205@localhost ~]$ egrep '^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$' sample.txt
[cmps205@localhost ~]$ egrep '^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+' sample.txt
We are learning NLP
Good Bye
Regular expression
American University of Beirut
Graduate Students
Lab session
Welcome to Lebanon
Tomorrow Holiday

Comment: @AmineBekki Probably trailing spaces. Try `'^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+ *$'`.

Comment: thank you @melpomene, adding the *$ still didnt solve it

Comment: The @choroba grep solution (**not egrep - just grep**)works fine with your sample.txt in my `GNU bash, version 4.4.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.  It prints only the lines with two words . If you don't see output maybe it is a different problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close.

Try this:

```
sort text.txt | uniq -c | sort -m | egrep "^[ \t]* [0-9]+ [^ ]* [^ ]*$" | sort -n
```

Sort the file. 
Get a count of the unique lines. 
Sort that output.
Finally, find the lines that 3 columns.

My output looked like this:

```
        $ sort text.txt | uniq -c | sort -m | egrep "^[ \t]* [0-9]+ [^ ]* [^ ]*$" | sort -n
        16 wE1 wE2
        17 wD1 wD2
        18 wC1 wC2
        19 wB1 wB2
        20 wA1 wA2
```

Cheers.